# jquery determine name/id of form on submit

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery code running on document.ready

```
formobj.submit(function(e){
  if ( submitted ) {
    return false;
  } else {
    submitted = true;
    return true;
  }
});
```

There are often multiple forms on the page. i need to know which form triggered the submission. I see that the "e" object has a target value, but can't seem to tap into it to retrieve the unique id.

Answer (score 4):

HTML:

```
<form id="my_form" method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.id); // my_form
    // equivalent to
    console.log($(this).attr('id')); // my_form 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It should work with `e.target.id`. But as you are using jQuery, you can also try `$(this).attr('id')`.

Of course the forms need to have a proper ID set.

The same applies to `name`.

Answer (score 0):

The 'this' object should be bound to the submitting form in the context of the event handler.  For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
<form id="aForm1"><input type="submit"/></form>
<form id="aForm2"><input type="submit"/></form>
<form id="aForm3"><input type="submit"/></form>
<script src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        $(document.body).append('which form is this?: ' + String(this.id));
        $(document.body).append($('<br/>'));
        e.preventDefault();
        });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

You can see an example of this running here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/HNVyU/